# Why does oninput sometimes not fire for file type input?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am having issues with the code bellow. The function `loadFile` returns a promise that resolves to a file (blob) received from an input element. 90% of the time this code works as intended. A file open dialog appears and if I select an image file and click open the image is loaded and appended to the document body and the message "Resolving promise!" appears in the console. However, about 10% of the time I will select an image and click open, and then nothing will happen. No messages or errors appear in the console. The open file dialog simply closes and despite having selected an image the `oninput` handler never appears to fire as the promise never resolves. I suspect this may be a bug in Chrome.

```
function loadFile() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const input = document.createElement("input")
        input.type = "file"
        input.oninput = function() {
            console.log("Resolving promise!")
            resolve(input.files[0])
        }
        input.click()
    })
}

async function imageFromFile() {
    const file = await loadFile()
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    const image = new Image()
    image.src = url
    await image.decode()
    return image
}

imageFromFile().then(img => {
    document.body.append(img)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your async function in a try catch block (and log the error) to see what happens that 10% of times.

```html
try {
  await loadFile()
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Does nothing. Besides, if something was being thrown Chrome Dev Tools would already be logging an "Uncaught (in promise)" error message.